# Using MATCH Function with Table Headers in VBA

Tags: vba, match, excel-2016

I'm trying to use the MATCH function to determine a row.  I have several holes and some of the holes go through numerous parts (ex: hole 1 could go through two parts, but Hole 2, next to it, could go through four parts).  The diameters could be different in each layer, and can vary by quite a bit.  I need to pull the correct diameter for the layer.  My code works up to the line where I try to get j equal to the row number that the next hole is on.  I think my problem is with the range.  I'd like to use the table header, since the input table size can vary from project to project.

I updated the code to reflect the suggestions in the comment and the research I was able to do to use the table header in the MATCH function.  The issue now is that it pulls the row below what I would have anticipated.  Using the code on the example table, j , the row that MATCH returns, is 5, which is a row for Hole 3, unless it counts the header row, but I thought that using dataBodyRange would exclude that row.  Note that my table begins at cell A5.  I think I still have a reference issue.

[image: Example Table]

```
Private Sub UpdatePitchDia_Click()
'Want to use diameters from the same part

Dim i
Dim j
Dim LastRowIn
Dim Hole_Num
Dim Incoming_Dia
Dim Hole_L
Dim Hole_R
Dim Hole_U
Dim Hole_D
Dim Stack_Up
Dim Stack_Up_L
Dim L_Dia

Dim tbl_In As ListObject
Dim Hole As Range

Set tbl_In = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").ListObjects("tbl_Input")
Set Hole = tbl_In.ListColumns(1).Range

LastRowIn = tbl_In.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

i = 1
j = 0


 
For i = 1 To LastRowIn Step 1

    Hole_L = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 4)
    
    If Not IsEmpty(Hole_L) Then  'Not all holes have adjacent holes
            
        'Need to make sure that the part layers are the same
        j = WorksheetFunction.Match(Hole_L, Hole, 0)
        
        'MsgBox "Row of Hole Left (" & Hole_L & ") is " & j
        
        Stack_Up = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 2)
        Stack_Up_L = [tbl_Input].Cells(j, 2)
        
        If Stack_Up <> Stack_Up_L Then
            j = j + 1
            Stack_Up_L = [tbl_Input].Cells(j, 2)
            
            Else: L_Dia = [tbl_Input].Cells(j, 3)
        End If
    End If
        
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: why are you using `[tbl_Input]` if you already have the variable `tbl_In`? Then, the value of `Hole_L` will never change: `Hole_L = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 4)` should be inside the loop.

Comment: I always get a runtime error when I use tbl_In for anything other than setting LastRowIn.